Обработка исключения из вложенного catch
Есть у меня такая функция:
try {
    $this->commandBus->dispatch($command);
} catch (Throwable $exception) {
    Yii::$app->errorHandler->logException($exception);
    throw new ApiServerException();
}

dispatch вызывает примерно такую функцию:
try {
    $service = $this->serviceRepository->findById($command->serviceId);
    $workerId = $this->workerRepository->findById($command->workerId);
    $worker = new Worker($workerId, $command->workersCount, $command->addedType, $command->companyGroupId, $command->botCityId);
    $service->assignWorker($worker);
    $this->serviceRepository->save($service);
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}

Вообщем суть вопроса если я внутри disaptch могу отловить ошибку которая на данные момент у меня просто print_r. Могу ли я передать её в перехватчик выше ?? Чтобы там обработать.

Можете. Надо убрать try catch

Или выбросить эксепшен снова в блоке catch

throw $e допишите при отлове и улетит дальше. Если нужен отлов в вызываемом коде вообще.
